# how to get the value from one activity to another

Tags: android, string, android-intent, null

I want to pass a value from one avtivity to another activity by use intent.. Im not getting the value im getting as null..  There is no error in my logcat.  Any help would appreciated. thanks in advance.

> First activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Nexttopic.this, Quesans.class);
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        intent.putExtra("TopicName", tname);
        intent.putExtra("Topicid", topicid);
        intent.putExtra("LevelName",TAG_LEVELNAME);
        intent.putExtra("Levelid",TAG_LEVELID);
        intent.putExtra("Groupid",TAG_GROUPID);
 startActivity(intent);
```

> Second activity

```
    Intent i=getIntent();
    name=i.getStringExtra(tname);
    tid=i.getStringExtra(topicid);
    lid=i.getStringExtra(TAG_LEVELID);
    gid=i.getStringExtra(TAG_GROUPID);
    System.out.println("Result :"+name);
    System.out.println("Result :"+tid);
    System.out.println("Result :"+lid);
    System.out.println("Result :"+gid);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the names of extra fields you have set while calling another activity.
So Change this :

```
Intent i=getIntent();
name=i.getStringExtra(tname);
tid=i.getStringExtra(topicid);
lid=i.getStringExtra(TAG_LEVELID);
gid=i.getStringExtra(TAG_GROUPID);
System.out.println("Result :"+name);
System.out.println("Result :"+tid);
System.out.println("Result :"+lid);
System.out.println("Result :"+gid);
```

to this :

```
Intent i=getIntent();
name=i.getStringExtra("TopicName");
tid=i.getStringExtra("Topicid");
lid=i.getStringExtra("Levelid");
gid=i.getStringExtra("Groupid");
System.out.println("Result :"+name);
System.out.println("Result :"+tid);
System.out.println("Result :"+lid);
System.out.println("Result :"+gid);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

you should do this way

**Second activity**

```
Intent i=getIntent();
name=i.getStringExtra("TopicName");
```

whenever u get result in Second Activity data Access By KEY not VALUE.

Like:

```
  name=i.getStringExtra("TopicName");
```

Answer (score 1):

While getting value from extra your `String name` should be same as you passing in putextra.

While passing@

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Nexttopic.this, Quesans.class);
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        intent.putExtra("TopicName", tname);
        intent.putExtra("Topicid", topicid);
        intent.putExtra("LevelName",TAG_LEVELNAME);
        intent.putExtra("Levelid",TAG_LEVELID);
        intent.putExtra("Groupid",TAG_GROUPID);
 startActivity(intent);
```

While getting@

```
     Intent i=getIntent();
     name=i.getStringExtra("TopicName");
     tid=i.getIntExtra("Topicid",0); 
     lid=i.getIntExtra("Levelid",0); 
     gid=i.getIntExtra("Groupid",0); 
     System.out.println("Result :"+name);
     System.out.println("Result :"+tid);
     System.out.println("Result :"+lid);
     System.out.println("Result :"+gid);
```

> I assume tid,lid,gid are integer.

[putExtras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

[getExtras()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29)

Comment: The method getInt(String) is undefined for the type Intent  showing this error..what i want to do..

Comment: Im getting the value as 0. My id values should get from database. now if i get the topicname is enough..

Comment: 0 is the default value when you didn't get any value from putextra it will give you 0 as default, check value while passing in put extras, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity..
give like this

in your first activity make the tname and topicid and other strings as public and use them in your second activity as like this

**Second activity**

```
Intent i=getIntent();
name=i.getStringExtra(Nexttopic.tname);
tid=i.getStringExtra(Nexttopic.topicid);
```

Answer (score 0):

First Activity

```
 Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("wid", wid);
   i.putExtra("rid", rid);
  startActivity(i);
```

Second Activity

```
Bundle b = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    wid = b.getString("wid");
    rid = b.getString("rid");
```

Answer (score 0):

When getting  value  from  child intent your String name should be same as you passing in parent  intent. You can pass string values as well a list of class can be passes through intent. There is another way of taking value from hash map is available. Just google it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14393309/1697047 is one kind which is a essay way